# Prove that $f(c)>f(b)$ using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $(a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. $f'<0$ on $(a, b)$. Let $c\in (a, b)$. Prove that $f(c)>f(b)$.

**I know this an easy problem and there are lots of ways of doing it, but I want it to be done my way only.**

Here's my attempt:

Take $e>0$ so that $c<b-e$ i.e. $e<b-c$

$f'<0$ on $(a, b)$. So, $f$ is decreasing on $(a, b)$.

$\implies f(c)>f(b-e)\ \forall\ 0<e<b-c$

Now I need to use the fact that $f$ is continuous at $b$ to prove that $f(c)>b$. The definition of continuity at $b$ is: $\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(b)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-b|<\delta$.

What do I choose as $\epsilon$ in order to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: Hint: mean value theorem

Comment: I know that you want to do it "your way" but I suggest you invoke the mean value theorem.

Comment: Fix $e$, and then just take for example $\epsilon<(f(c)-f(b-e))/2$.

Comment: You have $f(c)>f(b-e)$ for all $0<e<b-c$. Then $f(c)>\lim_{e \to 0} f(b-e)=f(b)$ because $f$ is continuous at $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Take arbitrary $x\in (a,b)$.

$f(c) - f(b) = (c-b)\cdot\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c} = (b-c)\cdot f(\xi)$, for some 
$\xi\in(c,b)$ by Lagrange theorem. Now, $b-c > 0$, and $f(\xi) < 0$, so $f(b) - f(c)$ has to be less than zero. We can conclude, that $f(b) < f(c)$.